# when().thenAnswer() not firing in blocTest

Tags: flutter, dart, unit-testing, mockito

Writing unit tests using mockito and the `@GenerateNiceMocks` annotation trying to test a cubit function, but none of the `when().thenAnswer()` lines seem to be working. When debugging the test and checking the local variables of that function, all of them are set to `null` instead of what was put in `thenAnswer()`.

**Function being tested**

```dart
Future<void> loadStoredCredentials() async {
  String? email = await storage.read(key: AuthenticationKeys.rememberEmail);
  String? str = await storage.read(key: AuthenticationKeys.rememberMeKey);
  String? lastViewedMessages = await storage.read(
    key: 'lastViewedMessages',
  );

  bool rememberMe = false;
  if (str != null) {
    rememberMe = true;
  }

  if (email != null) {
    emit(state.copyWith(
      username: email,
      usernameValid: FieldValidity.valid,
      rememberMe: rememberMe,
      lastViewedMessages: lastViewedMessages,
    ));
  }
}
```

**Test file**

```dart
@GenerateNiceMocks([MockSpec<FlutterSecureStorage>()])

void main() async {
  TestWidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  SignInCubit? signInCubit;

  setUp(() async {
    signInCubit = SignInCubit();
  });

  group('MockFlutterSecureStorage tests -', () {
    setUpAll(() => FlutterSecureStorage.setMockInitialValues({}));

    final email = Future.value('test@test.test');
    final flag = Future.value('true');
    final nullFuture = Future.value('');

    blocTest<SignInCubit, SignInCubitState>(
      'loadStoredCredentials - success',
      build: () => SignInCubit(),
      act: (cubit) async {
        final storage = MockFlutterSecureStorage();

        when(storage.read(key: AuthenticationKeys.rememberEmail))
            .thenAnswer((_) => email);
        when(storage.read(key: AuthenticationKeys.rememberMeKey))
            .thenAnswer((_) => flag);
        when(storage.read(key: 'lastViewedMessages'))
            .thenAnswer((_) => nullFuture);

        await cubit.loadStoredCredentials();
      },
      expect: () => (isA<SignInCubitState>),
    );
  });
}
```

**Test error**

```
Expected: <Closure: () => TypeMatcher<SignInCubitState> from Function 'isA': static.>
  Actual: []

package:test_api                             expect
package:bloc_test/src/bloc_test.dart 220:16  testBloc.<fn>
===== asynchronous gap ===========================
dart:async                                   _CustomZone.registerUnaryCallback
package:bloc_test/src/bloc_test.dart 201:7   testBloc.<fn>
dart:async                                   runZonedGuarded
package:bloc_test/src/bloc_test.dart 199:9   testBloc
package:bloc_test/src/bloc_test.dart 156:13  blocTest.<fn>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was optional dependency injection.

**Function being tested**

```dart
Future<void> loadStoredCredentials({FlutterSecureStorage? storage}) async {
  FlutterSecureStorage _storage = storage ?? fSecureStorage;

  String? email = await _storage.read(
    key: AuthenticationKeys.rememberEmail,
  );
  String? str = await _storage.read(
    key: AuthenticationKeys.rememberMeKey,
  );
  String? lastViewedMessages = await _storage.read(
    key: AuthenticationKeys.lastViewed,
  );

  bool rememberMe = false;
  if (str != null) {
    rememberMe = true;
  }

  if (email != null) {
    emit(state.copyWith(
      username: email,
      usernameValid: FieldValidity.valid,
      rememberMe: rememberMe,
      lastViewedMessages: lastViewedMessages,
    ));
  }
}
```

**Passing test**

*Switched to using `mocktailx` instead of `mockito`, hence syntax change*

```dart
blocTest<SignInCubit, SignInCubitState>(
  'loadStoredCredentials - success',
  build: () => SignInCubit(),
  act: (cubit) async {
    when(() => mockStorage.read(key: AuthenticationKeys.rememberEmail))
        .thenAnswerWith('t@t.io');
    when(() => mockStorage.read(key: AuthenticationKeys.rememberMeKey))
        .thenAnswerWith('true');
    when(() => mockStorage.read(key: AuthenticationKeys.lastViewed))
        .thenAnswerWith('time');

    await cubit.loadStoredCredentials(storage: mockStorage);
  },
  expect: () => <SignInCubitState>[
    const SignInCubitState(
      username: 't@t.io',
      usernameValid: FieldValidity.valid,
      rememberMe: true,
      lastViewedMessages: 'time',
    ),
  ],
);
```